# Ansible fetching Stdout key value

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, dictionary, ansible, amazon-ecs

I need some help regarding, how to fetch specific value using Ansible

My task:

```yaml
- name: 'check Describe Information'
  debug: 
  var: describeresult.stdout
```

I need IP address value from below stdout, what should I put in debug var to fetch IP address

```
TASK [check Describe Information] **********************************************
task path: /home/tom/Getipaddress.yml:28
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "describeresult.stdout": {
        "failures": [], 
        "tasks": [
            {
                "attachments": [
                    {
                        "details": [
                            {
                                "name": "subnetId", 
                                "value": "subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "name": "networkInterfaceId", 
                                "value": "eni-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "name": "macAddress", 
                                "value": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "name": "privateIPv4Address", 
                                "value": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                            }
```

Plus I am using AWS ECS command to generate the above output with `--output` as a JSON not sure how to use `--query` to filter or fetch above IP address only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter). For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_privateIPv4Address: "{{ describeresult.stdout.tasks|
                                   json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        query: "[].attachments[].details[?name=='privateIPv4Address'].value"
```

`json_query` returns by default a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this for getting private IP address only
`"{{describeresult.stdout['tasks'][0]['attachments'][0]['details'][3]['value']}}"`

The above might have slight syntax issues but should work.

I have done something like this earlier for ec2_group_info module in ansible

You can start off by generating output in pieces `describeresult.stdout['tasks']` should return JSON for the task attribute. 
`[0]` indicates the first element when there is a box bracket for a JSON implying more than one element/list.
Let me know how it goes.